# jQuery: Make items that haven't been clicked disappear

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game using jQuery. When the user has made his choice and has clicked one button, I want the other buttons to disappear. This is what I've tried:

```
$('.choice1').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
    if ($('.choice1').css('background-color') != 'red') {
        $(this).hide();
    }
})
```

When I try to run it, whichever button I pressed disappears though. What can I do to fix this/ what did I do wrong?
I was thinking of using a for-loop to iterate through the buttons but I have no idea how to do that.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="main">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Computer's Choice:</h3>
            <div class="choices">
                <button class="choice btn btn-submit">Rock</button>
                <button class="choice btn btn-submit">Paper</button>
                <button class="choice btn btn-submit">Scissors</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Player's Choice:</h3>
            <div class="choices">
                <button class="choice1 btn btn-submit">Rock</button>
                <button class="choice1 btn btn-submit">Paper</button>
                <button class="choice1 btn btn-submit">Scissors</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: post the HTML for ALL buttons please

Comment: I just edited the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them all the same class name and hide not($(this)):

```
<div class="choice1">
Rock
</div>
<div class="choice1">
Paper
</div>
<div class="choice1">
Scissors
</div>

$('.choice1').on('click', function () {
   $('.choice1').not($(this)).hide();
})
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/xv66zw3k/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 $this.addClass('active');
 $('button').not($this).hide();
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Rock</button>
<button>Paper</button>
<button>Scissors</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are siblings of each other, you could hide them by selecting the siblings of the clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".option").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().css("opacity", 0);
  })
})
```

```css
.option {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
  <div class="option"></div>
  <div class="option"></div>
  <div class="option"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo for you. Im totally done it by using class changes which is making it clear and smart. Simple definition is I'm styling them with a class that all three uses commonly. Then I created a class named 'hide'. That class has only display:none value. I catch the clicked element with function var and add all of them hide class then remove the hide class from catched one.

[**View Demo**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=ff85b4eaef2a41bfd0bf1f0ee5a49272)